# PHPExcel in Heroku does not find PHPExcel_Shared_String

Tags: php, heroku, phpexcel

I have to write and read a file excel in php... I have found a library called PHPExcel (i think it does not work very good and I would like to change it with another one)... however...

PHPExcel works in local but not on Heroku... so I removed any reference to PHPExcel and I kept just this line:

```
/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
```

But I receive the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found in /app/Classes/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php on line 11

What I have discovered:

`PHPExcel_Shared_String` is defined inside the file `String.php` that is inside the path `/app/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared`

So perhaps (? i am not good in php) the path where it look for the class is wrong?

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

**EDIT**
On Heroku I should have PHP 7 installed according to Heroku support:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/777

this is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which PHP version?

Comment: Local: PHP version 7.0.(something i do not remember).. on heroku I am trying to understand

Comment: have you make sure that this `PHPExcel/Shared/String.php` exists in your file system?

Comment: yes the file exists both on local system and heroku

Comment: In Heroku I should have PHP 7 installed... see the update on the post please

Comment: On more question about your composer version? because it seems to be an old one and may be it is causing the problem

Comment: Composer version 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was Heroku + Dropbox.... for some reason heroku was not synchronized correctly... so all folders inside `Classes/PhpExcel` stayed only on dropbox. I solved moving the project on GitHub and using GitHub as repository for Heroku...